# Linux Kernel and KVM

Tags: linux-networking, kvm-virtualization, hypervisor

I am new to the concept of building your server and was reading about Hypervisors. I learnt that KVM is type 1 hypervisor and can be installed directly on the server without OS. But what confused me is that to install KVM module you need linux kernel. So how do you create a bootable drive with hypervisor and KVM installed and no need to install a Linux distribution first. Could not find any article that explains this concept or maybe my understanding is not right.

Comment: "without OS" - what this actually means is causing the confusion here. You need a running kernel, you need some facility for interacting with the kernel. While you don't need all the tools in a standard Linux distribution you do need more than just the kernel - i.e. you need an operating system.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is based on a false predicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A hypervisor needs to duplicate a lot of the functionality of an OS: it needs to manage CPU cycles and allocate them to VMs, it needs to manage storage and allocate it to VMs, etc.

The developers of KVM thought to themselves: why should we develop all of this from scratch when we have a perfectly good implementation of scheduling, resource allocation, security, device drivers, etc. right here in the Linux kernel?

So, what KVM does, is *use the Linux kernel as the hypervisor*. In other words, KVM is a type 1 hypervisor that also happens to be an existing OS kernel.